# How to override a code in standard python library?

Tags: scikit-image

while executing the model.fit_generator code in my python image processing program, I came across this error "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/exposure/exposure.py:351: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  image = (image - imin) / float(imax - imin)"

I need to know how can I override the code in skimage/exposure.py so that I can get past the error. I know what the new code should look like in skimage/exposure.py but I don't know how to override the module in my python 3.6 program.

I tried copying the entire code of skimage/exposure.py in my python program and put in my piece of code but it did not get picked up and I ended up getting the error again.

skimage/exposure.py has this code

```
if imin != imax:
    image = (image - imin) / float(imax - imin)
```

I want to override it into my program as

```
if imax != imin:
    image = (image - imin)/float(imax - imin)
else:
    image = image - imin
```

I want to know how I can override the skimage/exposure.py code in my python program.

Comment: you can copy your edited code into a file and import that?

Comment: @Piakkaa, suppose I copy my code to a file and import it, how do I make sure that my code gets picked up and not the skimage/exposure.py code?

Comment: well you name it differently and import it under different name. If you are using python 3.6+ then you wanna put . before the name of package eg import .exposure

Comment: btw dont name it exposure, name it something different

Comment: I imported the new custom module to my python program but still the old skimage/exposure is getting picked up and firing the error, anyway that I can shut it off so that my module can pick over ?